# Unable to display an image from within Jar file

Tags: java, image, swing

I know this has been asked before but I can't get it to work after trying all variations.I have a small program that I'm wanting the launch frame to have an image displayed on it. I can achieve this by having the jar in the same folder as the image and referencing it, however when I try to reference within the jar file itself I keep getting error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
```

The code I am using is this:

```
private void imagePanel() {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    BufferedImage image;
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("/src/ticketMaster/img/logo.png"));
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image)), BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
```

I'm not sure if the path is incorrect, I have made a img folder inside the package named img which contains the logo. I have tried all variations of it

```
/img/logo.png
/ticketMaster/img/logo.png
/src/ticketMaster/img/logo.png
```

I am not able to get the image to load like I would just referencing the image outside of the jar. I've used resourceasstream as well and not had any luck with that.

Any ideas here?

Comment: You're missing details - where, exactly, is the image stored in relationship to the top level `src` folder?  You should never reference `src` - it won't exist when packaged.  Unzip the Jar file and make sure the image is been included.  Repeated posting isn't going to go do well, unless you can provide some information about why the other solutions didn't work for.  My guess, based on your what you're providing is either the path is wrong or the image is not included in your Jar

Comment: It's in the root folder of the package, I have tried taking it out and just putting the image directly in the root folder too and that doesn't work.

Comment: *"It's in the root folder of the package"* - The itself is?  Then use `/logo.png` as the path

Comment: Please don't re-ask the same question as this is against site rules.

Comment: Okay, so I packaged again and it's not putting the image in the jar file only classes into the jar. I have the info folder added in my run config in eclipse. Not sure what I'm doing wrong there

Comment: The first time I asked this question it said that it was closed by moderator and linked to different questions that were similar situation. My bad.

Answer (score -2):

I dont know your folder or your package structure, but you can try to remove the first '/' for the path you given in the getRessource() method, it may be looking for a absulute path.